# MediaRetriever for artist returning null

Tags: android

artist is gettiing initialised value only,.not the artistextracted using metadata
plz suggest me wat wrong i am  doing

```
 Strng artist="";
        void onCreate(){
            metaRetriver1 = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
            metaRetriver1.setDataSource("/storage/sdcard0/Tu+Jo+Hain.mp3");

            artist=metaRetriver1.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_ARTIST);

        }
```

Answer (score 1):

`listFiles` returns `null`, if the file is not a directory or an I/O error occurs, hence you should check against possible null values.

Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() returns already the path to your external storage directory. So instead of having

```
 String root_sd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
 file = new File( root_sd + "/external_sd" ) ;       
 File list[] = file.listFiles();
```

you can simply have

```
File list[] = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().listFiles();
```

be aware that from api level 19 you should add [READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) to your AndroidManifest.xml file

Answer (score 1):

add a check for null in your list

```
if(list!=null){
            for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
                myList.add(list[i].getName());
            }
        }
```

also check if the directory from which you are getting files exists or not.

Comment: yup.i will add..thanx

Comment: if my answer helps you, then please mark this as useful or flag it.

Comment: .ur answer is helpful .but i cant upvote it as i am new here and having less reutation.but my activity still not working properly i am checking that will update question soon :).plz dont mind